# Yii Slugs using url manager

Tags: yii, url-rewriting, yii-url-manager

So using yii I want to have urls like this:

```
mydomain.com/some-short-slug
```

And this url to map the following:

```
mydomain.com/book?bookslug=some-short-slug
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need do this inside url-manager:

```
 'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => false,
        'rules' => array(
            ...
            '<slug>'=>'book/index'
            ...
        ),
```

Now, if url like `mydomain.com/some-short-slug`, you have `$slug` equal to "some-short-slug" in the `actionIndex` of `BookController`

Comment: You will also need an .htaccess file or equivalent single entry point redirect as described in the Yii docs - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x